# How to add the 256 value only to negative numbers?Result i get from modorg is the same as modulus

Tags: android, arrays

```
//arrays modulus and modrog

byte[] modulus ={-30, 0 , 25, 70,-25,-3,-2};  
byte[] modorg=new byte[7];

//the loop that counts the elements

for (int j = 0; j < modulus.length; j++)
{
    if (modulus[j] < 0)
    {
        modorg[j] = (byte) ((int)modulus[j] + 256);
    }
    else
    {
        modorg[j]=modorg[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @arianit. Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a *question-and-answer* site. Since your post doesn't include a question, it is hard to know what you expect us to answer.

Comment: The question is in the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 256 to a byte is like adding 360 to a degree :)
You will get the same value.
You probably want to add 128?